# Having a tooltip or pop up for abbreviations

Tags: html

I have text that is like :

```
"<h4>If the Client&#39;s EMR/EHR/Billing System supports HL-7 Standards (HL-7 Compatible), can integrate with the client&#39;s system through HL-7<br> Messaging to retrieve the information it needs to process the charges, rejections and denials for the client.</h4>
<h3 style= "color:#008080;">This approach consists of the following technical steps:</h3>
<div class="well" style= "color:#990012; font-size:18px">
1-  will setup a secure FTP site for the client&#39;s EMR/EHR/Billing System.
2- This is an EHR example and JAS </div>
```

I have a code with a lot of text like this. I want to be able to hover over the abbreviations (EHR, HL-7, EMR) and for a tooltip to pop up with the whole word like for "EHR", "Electronic health record", "HL-7" = "health level" and so on, I tried the tool-tip like this:

```
<h4>If the Client&#39;s <div class="tooltip">EMR/EHR/Billing <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div> System supports
```

But then I EMR/EHR disappeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approach is to use an `<abbr>` tag:

```
<abbr title="Electronic health record">EHR</abbr>
```

You can then style it as you wish (for example, add an underline to indicate that people can hover over to see the tooltip).

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4pLr22h4/)

Comment: Yes this works for me, but would it work if I wanted the box to look like a popup?

Comment: @Serena, what exactly do you mean by 'popup'? Something like [this small library](https://eliorshalev.github.io/tootik/) does?

Comment: No, you can't really change how a `title` tooltip looks. You would have to make your own, or use a library like @elektronik suggested.

Answer (score 0):

To use the built-in functionality of the `<abbr>` you need the `title` attribute with the full name of your abbreviation:

```html
<abbr title="World Health Organization">WHO</abbr>
```

For *just a pop-up*, consider following [W3 Schools Tutorial.](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp) It uses simple CSS styles to give you the desired effect and no external libraries are needed.